# How to send url of current page with Ninja Forms entry

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to send the url of the page where the form is submitted. [Example](https://advancias.com/?s=ineedthisurl): 
Is there any built in way to send the url of the page the form is submitted on or is Javascript needed? I'm using Ninja Forms.

**Note:** Ninja Forms uses things like these to send info in hidden fields: {wp:post_url}

Comment: add link and reformat

Answer (score 0):

Either Javascript:

- `window.location.href` gives you the URL

or you can edit the PHP file which receives the form:

- `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` returns the URL you want